# Quick Measure Error: "Only Power BI-provided date hierarchies are supported"

Tags: date, powerbi, measure

I am attempting to create a rolling average quick measure using time intelligence. When I drop my DATE variable into the Date field I get the error message "Only Power BI-provided date hierarchies are supported".

How do I fix this? I've tried to use the solution posted [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Time-intelligence-does-not-work/td-p/279520) but it is not working for me. My date column is also formatted as  date/time. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.

The quick measures feature only works on very simple data models ( a single table).  Doesn't scale to well.

The easiest method is to create the moving average measure yourself using DAX.  No limitations that way.  Quick measure is just a way to generate DAX code through the GUI.

See this guide: https://www.daxpatterns.com/statistical-patterns/#moving-average   or https://powerpivotpro.com/2013/07/moving-averages-sums-etc/

Answer (score -1):

"Only Power BI-provided date hierarchies are supported".
such an Error occurs When you create a date table by adding manually New columns like the date column, year column, etc.

Instead of it Create a Date Column using ADDCOLUMNS(Calendarauto.....), it will automatically create date hierarchies.

**Solution no.2**

In your table make the date column in the hierarchy in Model View Tab.